# Selenium, Scrapy Iteration (click next) only extract href of items from first page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I try to extract the href of each item (six per page). To go to the next page I use next_click(). Selenium webdriver opens and clicks through all pages (Fine so far). But only extract the items from the first page. And that five times (as much as pages exist). It seems like, it recognize the correct number of items, but extract only the items of the first page all over again. Note: the url remains the same if you click on next page. Thanks a lot for your help!

```
import scrapy
from pprint import pprint
import time
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from selenium import webdriver
class contentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "university"
    start_urls = [
            'http://unisg.prospective.ch/index.cfm'   
        ]
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        
        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="btn-forward"]')

            try:
                next.click()
   
                time.sleep(3)

                items = response.xpath('//div[@class="section group jobContent countJobRecords"]')
                for i in items:
                    list_div = s.xpath('.//div')
                    link = list_div.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
                    yield joblink_item(link=link)

            except:
                    break
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` is created by scrapy, while `self.driver` is a selenium object.
The two don't know about each other, and updating one won't automatically update the other.
As a result, you simply extract the same data from the same response over and over.

There are a few ways you can approach solving your problem:

1. Do everything in scrapy
2. Do everything in selenium
3. Get updated html from selenium and create new scrapy selectors

Since the website in question doesn't seem to require selenium at all (clicking the next button simply sends a post request), I would recommend the first option.

**Explanation of the Scrapy-only method:**

If you take a look at the network tab of your browser's developer tools when clicking the next page button, you will see a request with the folowing details:

[image: General]

[image: Form Data]

To get the data you want, you just need to modify and execute this request.
Testing shows that it's even possible to get all the data using a single request:

```
>>> request = scrapy.FormRequest(
...     url="http://unisg.prospective.ch/index.cfm",
...     formdata={"offset": "0", "limit": "30", "lang": "de", "query": ""},
... )
>>> fetch(request)
2020-11-05 11:36:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://unisg.prospective.ch/index.cfm> (referer: Non
e)
>>> len(response.css('.jobContent'))
30
```

Comment: Thx! The problem is, i find no solution or sample code, how to click the next button. I would be very thankful for a piece of code, how to click and execute the post request only with scrapy.

Comment: Thank you! It works now, with scrapy start_request method and the formdata